# How to get text box value to variable in php and post it with button

Tags: php, html, mysql

i have a code

```
  <form action="index.php" method="post">  
    <input type="text" name="jam" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Translate" />
    </form>



<?php
$conn = mysql_connect ("localhost", "root","")  or die (mysql_error());
mysql_set_charset('utf8',$conn);
mysql_select_db ("movedb");


$jam = $_POST['jam'];


$sql = mysql_query("select * from WORD where ENGLISH like '$jam%' Limit 15");


while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
    echo ' '.$row['ENGLISH']; 
echo ' - '.$row['SINHALA']; 
    echo '<br/>';

    }


?>
```

i want to post that text value like index.php?=text=(text box value here)

and i want to get that submited to $jam

Comment: Remove > from index.php-> <form action="index.php> in your code

Comment: Use Get method instead of POST, and i think u too dont want this = sign in ndex.php?=text=(text box value here) its going to be ndex.php?text=(text box value here)

Comment: url showing as index.php?jam=so&submit=Translate i want to remove &submit=Translate  code

Comment: just use  <input type="submit"> then

Comment: thank.. how can i convert index.php?jam=what urls to .html like /what.html

Comment: Use htaccess for URL re writing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Form method should be `get` not `post`.

Also, remove the `>` from your action. Small typo.

Try:

```
<form action="index.php" method="get">  
<input type="text" name="jam" />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Translate" />
</form>
```

Then you can do: `$jam = $_GET['jam'];`

Comment: i want to set my text box value to variable and post it with my link. like index.php?id=<my text box value here>

Comment: @user1939816 - change `name="jame"` to `name="id"` to do so.

Comment: the url showing as index.php?jam=so&submit=Translate i want to remove &submit=Translate this

Comment: working. thanks .. and i want to convert index.php?jam=what this php url to .html url how to do it

Comment: @sean accepted the answer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8562724/php-url-to-html-url  by this tutorial how can i change my index.php?jam=what to html ? like index.html?jam=what  ?

Comment: Thanks. As the link I sent you says, it uses the .htaccess file.

Comment: @sean can i change it to /(text box value).html